# Azure Pipeline: Pass System.Debug to a pwsh switch parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-core

How do I parse a variable which is either the string "True" or non-existent into a boolean?

I'm trying to pass the value of the predefined azure pipeline variable "system.debug" into a pwsh script as the argument to a switch parameter. I've tried both of these approaches:

```
-isDebug:([boolean]'$(System.Debug)')
-isDebug:$$(System.Debug)
```

Both of these approaches work when the "Enable system diagnostics" option is checked. It gets a value of "True" which I then must parse. However, if not checked the System.Debug variable doesn't exist at all, not false or null. This makes my parse fail below:

```
$isDebug = $false
if($$(System.Debug)){
  $isDebug = $$(System.Debug)
}
```

Error:

```
+   $isDebug = $$(System.Debug)
+                ~
Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to check if the environment variable exists with get-environmentVariable and if it does use the value, otherwise don't pass the switch parameter at all.

```
      if([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('SYSTEM_DEBUG') -ne $null){
        write-host "SYSTEM_DEBUG: $(system.debug)"
        ./myscript.ps1 -isDebug:([boolean]$($env:SYSTEM_DEBUG))
      }
      else {
        write-host "SYSTEM_DEBUG was not set"
        ./myscript.ps1
      }
```

Comment: Hi JDH, thanks for your sharing! Please [mark your solution as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) of this question, it will helps others who meet the similar issue. :)